# Chapter 2, exercise 7 Rudin functional analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis

Follo up to [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745026/chapter-2-exercise-7-rudin-functional-analysis-clarification-of-multiplier-pr?noredirect=1#comment7701108_3745026), which I'm now trying to solve and to be honest I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing... so any help will be useful.

The textbook suggests to use the closed graph theorem first and then the riesz representation theorem.
If my understanding is correct the sequence $\left\{ \gamma_n \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is fixed and since $\Lambda : C(T) \to C(T)$ is defined as
$$
(\Lambda f)\hat{}(n) = \gamma_n \hat{f}(n)
$$
then $\Lambda$ is linear. I can conclude this from the relation
$$
\gamma_n\hat{f}(n) = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} (\Lambda f)(e^{i\theta})e^{-in\theta}d\theta
$$
Using the open mapping theorem I can show that $\Lambda$ is continuous since $C(T)$ is a Banach Space (hence an F-space), $\Lambda$ linear and the graph $\left\{(f,\Lambda f) : f \in C(T) \right\}$ is closed.

To prove the graph is closed I believe I can the remark from chapter 2

> If $\left\{x_n\right\}$ is a sequence in $X$ (F-space) such that the limits
> $$
> x = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n \;\;\; y = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Lambda x_n
> $$
> exists, then $y = \Lambda x$.

However I'm not sure how to apply it. My attempt was picking a convergent sequence $f_n$, and the computing

$$
\lim_{k \to+\infty} \Lambda f_k = \lim_{k\to+\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \gamma_n \hat{f_k}(n) e^{in\theta} =
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \gamma_n \left( \lim_{k\to+\infty}\hat{f_k}(n) \right)e^{in\theta} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \gamma_n \hat{f}(n)e^{in\theta} = \Lambda f
$$

but again, I'm not sure about my use of limits as well.

Then the graph is closed and hence $\Lambda$. By the closed graph theorem $\Lambda$ is continuous.

Here I got stuck.

Can you help/correct my approach or maybe give a different hint to solve it?

**Update**:

I gave another attempt to this problem. The author gives as hint to apply the closed graph theorem first. I'm considering the graph of $\Lambda$

$$
G_{\Lambda} = \left\{(f,\Lambda f) : f \in C(T) \right\} \subset C(T) \times C(T)
$$

To show the graph is closed, and hence $\Lambda$ continuous, I can apply the remark above. So given a convergent sequence $f_n \to f$ I want to show

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \Lambda f_n = \Lambda \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \right)
$$

hence I want to show that for all $\theta \in T$

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_T f(e^{i\theta}) D_n(\phi - \theta) d\theta = (\Lambda f)(e^{i\theta})
$$

where $D_n(\theta)$ is the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) however the Dirichlet kernel is an approximation of the identity, which implies the identity. Hence the graph is closed and therefore $\Lambda$ is continuous by the closed graph theorem.

Now I believe there's an error in the text indeed they define

$$
f \to \left(\Lambda f\right)(1) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} \gamma_n \hat{f}(n)
$$

However I believe the meant map is actually

$$
f \to \left( \Lambda f \right)(0) \;\;\;\; (1)
$$

Now the author suggests to use theorem 6.19 - [Real and Complex Analysis](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis.pdf) which I quote for convenience

> If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, then every bounded linear functional $\Phi$ on $C_0(X)$ is represented by a unique regular complex Borel measure $\mu$ , in the sense that
> $$
> \Phi f = \int_X f d\mu
> $$
> for every $f \in C_0(X)$. Moreover, the norm of $\Phi$ is the total variation of $\mu$
> $$
> \left\lVert \Phi \right\rVert = \left| \mu \right|(X)
> $$

Now I'm not sure how to apply the Riesz representation theorem, very informally the closest I came to was to assume $f \to \left( \Lambda f \right)(0)$ is a bounded linear functional (cause I'm not sure how to prove it). So I can apply the theorem to find a regular complex measure on $C(T)$ such that

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \gamma_n \hat{f}(n) = \int_T f d\mu = \int_T \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(n) e^{int} \right) d\mu
$$

The right most equality comes from the Fourier expansion of $f$ now comparing first and third member of the equality chain

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \gamma_n \hat{f}(n) = \int_T \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(n) e^{int} \right) d\mu \Rightarrow
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \gamma_n \hat{f}(n) - \int_T \left( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(n) e^{int} \right) d\mu = 0 \Rightarrow
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(n) \left[\gamma_n - \int_T e^{in\theta}d\mu \right]
$$

From which I would deduce

$$
\gamma_n = \int_T e^{in\theta} d\mu
$$

However none of the equalities are fully justified. The author suggests that the series $\left(\Lambda f\right) (0)$ may not converge and I should only be using it for trigonometric polynomials. I guess if I consider the subspace of trigonometric polynomials in $C(T)$ probably most of the math I did is actually justified, and since continuous functions might be approximated as much as I want with trigonometric polynomials I might end up with the result the exercise suggests?

Comment: You can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032345/application-of-the-riesz-theorem-to-fourier-series). It's a bit different from what you wrote, but I think it's translatable.

Comment: @DanielFischer How did you come up with the map $$x \to \int_T f(x + t) d\mu(t)$$ also how are you sure that the functional $$f \to \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \gamma_n \hat{f}(n)$$ is bounded? because only in that case you can apply the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: Second question first: $\Lambda$ is continuous by the closed graph theorem, and evaluation at $0$ is continuous, hence the composition of the two is continuous. Note however, that writing $f \mapsto (\Lambda f)(0)$ as $f \mapsto \sum \gamma_n \hat{f}(n)$ is problematic, the series doesn't necessarily converge for all $f \in C(T)$. As for the first question, that is addressed [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032345/application-of-the-riesz-theorem-to-fourier-series#comment4174206_2033088) under the answer. I knew I need a convolution, so I took a convolution.